# MySql DATE_FORMAT not working as expected

Tags: mysql

I am using whereBetween to fetch the data within a date range. Date is saved in AM/PM format in table. this is my query

```
SELECT * 
FROM `login_table` 
WHERE 
    `login_table`.`empid` IN ("1") AND
    DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(date_time_in, '%m/%d/%Y %l:%i:%s %p'), '%c/%d/%Y') BETWEEN '10/26/2019' AND '4/26/2021'
```

This is my table structure

```
   id  | empid   |   date_time_in
------------------------------------
1   |   1       |   1/23/2020 8:22:11 AM    
2   |   2       |   4/19/2014 1:14:40 PM    
3   |   1       |   11/26/2018 12:01:26 PM
4   |   1       |   3/3/2020 2:56:00 PM 



Expected result

id  | empid   |   date_time_in
------------------------------------
1   |   1       |   1/23/2020 8:22:11 AM    
4   |   1       |   3/3/2020 2:56:00 PM 

Getting result

id  | empid   |   date_time_in
------------------------------------
1   |   1       |   1/23/2020 8:22:11 AM    
3   |   1       |   11/26/2018 12:01:26 PM
4   |   1       |   3/3/2020 2:56:00 PM
```

Comment: You perform BETWEEN over text literals, not over dates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select * 
from `login_table` 
where `login_table`.`empid` in ("1") 
and STR_TO_DATE(date_time_in, '%m/%d/%Y %l:%i:%s %p') BETWEEN '2019-10-26' AND '2021-04-26'
```

Comment: Yes, this works fine. Thanks. Can you please tell me why this date format working `2019-10-26` and this is'nt `10/26/2019`

Comment: @jayantrawat Study [Date and Time Literals](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-literals.html).